# Azure python App Service crashes on startup with "/opt/startup/startup.sh: 32: /opt/startup/startup.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My Azure App service has been running without problems for over 2 years. For some reason, today the App Service has started throwing this error (as seen in the Log Stream)

```
2022-09-20T01:48:30.239101040Z   _____
2022-09-20T01:48:30.239108140Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____
2022-09-20T01:48:30.239112540Z  /  /_\  \___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \
2022-09-20T01:48:30.239116940Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/
2022-09-20T01:48:30.239121040Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2022-09-20T01:48:30.239125640Z         \/      \/                  \/
2022-09-20T01:48:30.239129840Z
2022-09-20T01:48:30.239133540Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2022-09-20T01:48:30.239137540Z
2022-09-20T01:48:30.239141340Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2022-09-20T01:48:30.239145340Z Python 3.9.7
2022-09-20T01:48:30.239149240Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2022-09-20T01:48:30.424663485Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2022-09-20T01:48:30.468606343Z Site's appCommandLine: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0 --workers 1 --timeout 1200 application:create_app()
2022-09-20T01:48:30.858384059Z Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
2022-09-20T01:48:30.858422059Z Launching oryx with: create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite -userStartupCommand 'gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0 --workers 1 --timeout 1200 application:create_app()'
2022-09-20T01:48:30.858428859Z Found build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'. Deserializing it...
2022-09-20T01:48:30.858433359Z Build Operation ID: |BPDiFi+oukQ=.99194caa_
2022-09-20T01:48:30.858437559Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20220812.1, Commit: cdf6b1bef165d05b94830e963646495967d938f4, ReleaseTagName: 20220812.1
2022-09-20T01:48:31.348409808Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2022-09-20T01:48:31.423025506Z Found virtual environment .tar.gz archive.
2022-09-20T01:48:31.426681211Z Removing existing virtual environment directory /antenv...
2022-09-20T01:48:31.495728503Z Extracting to directory /antenv...
2022-09-20T01:48:52.688655050Z Using packages from virtual environment antenv located at /antenv.
2022-09-20T01:48:52.689532751Z Updated PYTHONPATH to ':/opt/startup/app_logs:/opt/startup/code_profiler:/antenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages'
2022-09-20T01:48:52.692766855Z /opt/startup/startup.sh: 32: /opt/startup/startup.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
2022-09-20T01:49:03.031Z ERROR - Container customapi__b4ba_0_b6eb860f for site customapi__b4ba has exited, failing site start
2022-09-20T01:49:03.033Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container customapi__b4ba_0_b6eb860f_middleware for site customapi__b4ba
2022-09-20T01:49:06.318Z INFO  - Container customapi__b4ba_0_b6eb860f_middleware for site customapi__b4ba initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2022-09-20T01:49:06.386Z ERROR - Container customapi__b4ba_0_b6eb860f didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-09-20T01:49:06.419Z INFO  - Stopping site customapi__b4ba because it failed during startup.
```

I have tried updating the App Service to run with Python3.9 (it was previously running on Python 3.7), but the issue still persists.

Does anyone know why the startup.sh script is now throwing an error after several years of use? Why is this happening now, and how can I fix it?

Here are some container logs:

```
2022-09-20T01:48:24.614Z INFO  -  Status: Downloaded newer image for 10.0.4.254:13209/appsvc/python:3.9_20220818.1.tuxprod
2022-09-20T01:48:24.618Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 1 Minutes and 30 Seconds
2022-09-20T01:48:24.680Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2022-09-20T01:48:24.681Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 6740:8000 --name customapi__b4ba_0_b6eb860f -e WEBSITE_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=* -e WEBSITE_CORS_SUPPORT_CREDENTIALS=False -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=customapi -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=customapi.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=8e6219532b7937949116433adec046a116d12b4988fa8c712cf7d129bf896139 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=True appsvc/python:3.9_20220818.1.tuxprod gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0 --workers 1 --timeout 1200 application:create_app() 

2022-09-20T01:48:34.696Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container customapi__b4ba_0_b6eb860f for site customapi__b4ba
2022-09-20T01:48:50.130Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container customapi__b4ba_0_b6eb860f. Elapsed time = 15.433705 sec
2022-09-20T01:49:03.031Z ERROR - Container customapi__b4ba_0_b6eb860f for site customapi__b4ba has exited, failing site start
2022-09-20T01:49:03.033Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container customapi__b4ba_0_b6eb860f_middleware for site customapi__b4ba
2022-09-20T01:49:06.318Z INFO  - Container customapi__b4ba_0_b6eb860f_middleware for site customapi__b4ba initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2022-09-20T01:49:06.386Z ERROR - Container customapi__b4ba_0_b6eb860f didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-09-20T01:49:06.419Z INFO  - Stopping site customapi__b4ba because it failed during startup.
2022-09-20T01:56:56.412Z INFO  - Pulling image: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/middleware:stage5
2022-09-20T01:56:57.332Z INFO  - stage5 Pulling from appsvc/middleware
2022-09-20T01:56:57.363Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:f2a0c60712a928834c3dcc13c3f76f99bec497001417c303fed69c0a2a1bdac1
2022-09-20T01:56:57.371Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/middleware:stage5
2022-09-20T01:56:57.395Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
2022-09-20T01:56:57.424Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2022-09-20T01:56:57.425Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 7482:8181 -p 4775:8082 --name customapi__b4ba_0_a2022-09-20T01:57:00.921Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container customapi__b4ba_0_ad8d94a3 for site customapi__b4ba
2022-09-20T01:57:30.615Z ERROR - Container customapi__b4ba_0_ad8d94a3 for site customapi__b4ba has exited, failing site start
2022-09-20T01:57:30.617Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container customapi__b4ba_0_ad8d94a3_middleware for site customapi__b4ba
2022-09-20T01:57:34.296Z INFO  - Container customapi__b4ba_0_ad8d94a3_middleware for site customapi__b4ba initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2022-09-20T01:57:34.326Z ERROR - Container customapi__b4ba_0_ad8d94a3 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-09-20T01:57:34.344Z INFO  - Stopping site customapi__b4ba because it failed during startup.
2022-09-20T02:01:56.102Z INFO  - Pulling image: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/middleware:stage5
2022-09-20T02:01:57.514Z INFO  - stage5 Pulling from appsvc/middleware
2022-09-20T02:01:57.515Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:f2a0c60712a928834c3dcc13c3f76f99bec497001417c303fed69c0a2a1bdac1
2022-09-20T02:01:57.517Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/middleware:stage5
2022-09-20T02:01:57.520Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 1 Seconds
2022-09-20T02:01:57.558Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2022-09-20T02:01:57.561Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 6519:8181 -p 6613:8082 --name customapi__b4ba_0_92022-09-20T02:02:03.307Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container customapi__b4ba_0_90c34e20 for site customapi__b4ba
2022-09-20T02:02:18.758Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container customapi__b4ba_0_90c34e20. Elapsed time = 15.4515753 sec
2022-09-20T02:02:24.130Z ERROR - Container customapi__b4ba_0_90c34e20 for site customapi__b4ba has exited, failing site start
2022-09-20T02:02:24.132Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container customapi__b4ba_0_90c34e20_middleware for site customapi__b4ba
2022-09-20T02:02:27.422Z INFO  - Container customapi__b4ba_0_90c34e20_middleware for site customapi__b4ba initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2022-09-20T02:02:27.457Z ERROR - Container customapi__b4ba_0_90c34e20 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-09-20T02:02:27.465Z INFO  - Stopping site customapi__b4ba because it failed during startup.
2022-09-20T02:07:02.458Z INFO  - Pulling image: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/middleware:stage5
2022-09-20T02:07:03.170Z INFO  - stage5 Pulling from appsvc/middleware
2022-09-20T02:07:03.174Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:f2a0c60712a928834c3dcc13c3f76f99bec497001417c303fed69c0a2a1bdac1
2022-09-20T02:07:03.177Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/middleware:stage5
2022-09-20T02:07:03.180Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
2022-09-20T02:07:03.204Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2022-09-20T02:07:03.206Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 3406:8181 -p 7111:8082 --name customapi__b4ba_0_92022-09-20T02:07:06.557Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container customapi__b4ba_0_9517e44c for site customapi__b4ba
2022-09-20T02:07:24.676Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container customapi__b4ba_0_9517e44c. Elapsed time = 18.1187192 sec
2022-09-20T02:07:35.382Z ERROR - Container customapi__b4ba_0_9517e44c for site customapi__b4ba has exited, failing site start
2022-09-20T02:07:35.384Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container customapi__b4ba_0_9517e44c_middleware for site customapi__b4ba
2022-09-20T02:07:38.627Z INFO  - Container customapi__b4ba_0_9517e44c_middleware for site customapi__b4ba initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2022-09-20T02:07:38.655Z ERROR - Container customapi__b4ba_0_9517e44c didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-09-20T02:07:38.669Z INFO  - Stopping site customapi__b4ba because it failed during startup.
2022-09-20T02:12:05.944Z INFO  - Pulling image: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/middleware:stage5
2022-09-20T02:12:06.754Z INFO  - stage5 Pulling from appsvc/middleware
2022-09-20T02:12:06.757Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:f2a0c60712a928834c3dcc13c3f76f99bec497001417c303fed69c0a2a1bdac1
2022-09-20T02:12:06.759Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/middleware:stage5
2022-09-20T02:12:06.761Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
2022-09-20T02:12:08.324Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2022-09-20T02:12:08.326Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 3576:8181 -p 9646:8082 --name customapi__b4ba_0_82022-09-20T02:12:25.519Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container customapi__b4ba_0_86876b9b for site customapi__b4ba
2022-09-20T02:12:25.578Z ERROR - Container customapi__b4ba_0_86876b9b for site customapi__b4ba has exited, failing site start
2022-09-20T02:12:25.579Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container customapi__b4ba_0_86876b9b_middleware for site customapi__b4ba
2022-09-20T02:12:27.807Z INFO  - Container customapi__b4ba_0_86876b9b_middleware for site customapi__b4ba initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2022-09-20T02:12:27.838Z ERROR - Container customapi__b4ba_0_86876b9b didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-09-20T02:12:27.854Z INFO  - Stopping site customapi__b4ba because it failed during startup.
2022-09-20T02:16:56.823Z INFO  - Pulling image: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/middleware:stage5
2022-09-20T02:16:57.610Z INFO  - stage5 Pulling from appsvc/middleware
2022-09-20T02:16:57.612Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:f2a0c60712a928834c3dcc13c3f76f99bec497001417c303fed69c0a2a1bdac1
2022-09-20T02:16:57.618Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/middleware:stage5
2022-09-20T02:16:57.627Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
2022-09-20T02:16:57.647Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2022-09-20T02:16:57.649Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 5202:8181 -p 1785:8082 --name customapi__b4ba_0_12022-09-20T02:17:01.008Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container customapi__b4ba_0_10213bb4 for site customapi__b4ba
2022-09-20T02:17:24.074Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container customapi__b4ba_0_10213bb4. Elapsed time = 23.0655065 sec
2022-09-20T02:17:28.868Z ERROR - Container customapi__b4ba_0_10213bb4 for site customapi__b4ba has exited, failing site start
2022-09-20T02:17:28.870Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container customapi__b4ba_0_10213bb4_middleware for site customapi__b4ba
2022-09-20T02:17:32.265Z INFO  - Container customapi__b4ba_0_10213bb4_middleware for site customapi__b4ba initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2022-09-20T02:17:32.305Z ERROR - Container customapi__b4ba_0_10213bb4 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-09-20T02:17:32.318Z INFO  - Stopping site customapi__b4ba because it failed during startup.
```

Comment: can you please share the container logs

Comment: Hi @MohitGanorkar, just added container logs from KUDU

Answer (score 0):

If the container couldn't start or exited, There is possibility that Application may be facing any error or exception.

To narrow down the issue you can leverage diagnostic tool from the Azure Portal and select Application logs ; Container issues; container crash which helps in
investigating potential reasons why your container failed to start, which could cause deployment and availability issues.

You may examine both the deployment logs and the app logs for any error messages. These logs often identify specific issues that can prevent app deployment or app startup.

Check this detailed tutorial on [troubleshooting guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#troubleshooting),

[image]

Comment: I have utilised both of those tools, and narrowed down the issue to `/opt/startup/startup.sh: 32: /opt/startup/startup.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

I'm more concerned as to why this is now an issue when it wasn't previously? The App Service has run successfully for 2 years without an issue, why is this happening now?

The `/opt/startup/startup.sh` script is not something I have control over, it is part of the oryx build, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

I've had something similar with nodejs and `/opt/startup/startup.sh` script:

To my understanding (and this is not well documented) Azure Web App manages that default startup script using oryx and two scripts:

1. `/opt/startup/init_container.sh` - manages the initialization of the container + creates the startup script.
2. `/opt/startup/startup.sh` - the final script that will be used to start your application which is written in `shell`.

inside `init_container.sh` we can see the following lines:

```bash
STARTUP_CONNABD_PATH="/opt/startup/startup.sh"
ORYX_ARGS="create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output $STARTUP_COMMAND_PATH -defaultApp=/opt/startup/default-static-site.js -userStartupCommand '$@'"
```

And later in that same file, these `ORYX_ARGS` are executed:

```bash
eval oryx $ORYX_ARGS
```

My guess is that the startupCommand we provide under configuration is passed to `ORYX_ARGS` which in turn generates a new `/opt/start/startup.sh` script that doesn't have the default value.

If you were to pass something like main() in the startup command it would be added to `/opt/startup/startup.sh` as a shell command `main()`.

I did some digging, and apparently, the shell interpreter will throw an `unexpected (`  if it tries to interpret `main()` when there's no function named `main` ([related comment from the unix&linux stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45784)).

Back to your scenario, I can see there's `application()` in your startup command which is valid in the context of `gunicorn`, but not in the context of `shell`. I suggest wrapping it whole with double-quotes (`"`) and see what happens.